# Spring boot jsp not resolving

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a working boot MVC app that I need to add jsp views to .

I've added all the required jars

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

My view config in application.yml

```
spring:
 mvc:
view:
  prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
  suffix: .jsp
```

Added my jsp's to src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

my controller

```
@Controller
public class PreAuthController {

@RequestMapping( value="/" , method = RequestMethod.GET  )
public String index(){
    return "dashboard";
}

@RequestMapping( value="/dashboard" , method = RequestMethod.GET  )
public String dashboard(){
    return "dashboard";
}

@RequestMapping( value="/login" , method = RequestMethod.GET  )
    public String login(){
        return "login";
}

}
```

The logs show correct docroot

Document root: /Users/myhome/workspace/wi-preauth/wi-preauth-ui/src/main/webapp

When I try to hit http://localhost:8080/

I keep getting this error

```
Could not resolve view with name 'login' in servlet with name 
'dispatcherServlet'
```

I've tried everything from other question asked on the forums to no avail..

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create ApplicationContext java configuration class.

`ResourceHandlerRegistry` locations helps to register the paths to load static files like css, images, fonts and js files in JSP.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class ApplicationContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations(
                    "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        }
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(
                    CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue. I have a configuration class that extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport. This in turn disables WebMvcAutoConfiguration. 
So I had to add my own

```
@Bean
  public UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver() {
  UrlBasedViewResolver resolver
    = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
  resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
  return resolver;
 }
```

in my config.